# Windows 10 unable to show thumbnails preview for symbolic links. Any turnabouts to bypass limitations?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

Thumbnail preview works just fine in regards to original file, it ain't for symlinked ones.

**Link's property**

[image: IMG:]

Comment: What thumbnail is shown for the symlink files?

Comment: just common icon, in my case just simple .mp4 icon